# GWT: accents not displayed on Strings

Tags: java, gwt, encoding, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

In my GWT project I am initialization Strings with accents (acute), but on the next line (debugging on Eclipse) these accents are displayed as �. Same happens when I deploy.

```
String myText = "Título";
```

On Eclipse debugger (or deployed), `myText` is displayed as `T�tulo`.

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: make sure all your files are UTF8 encoded.

Comment: It was in ANSI. However, when I changed it to UTF8, I got this error message. Line 1: Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token. On line 1 there is no illegal character, and I cannot see anything besides the accent and a Spanish "ñ" (ntilde).

Comment: You have to _recode_ your file, not just change the setting on your IDE (which generally only tells it how to understand the bytes, and how to encode the file when _writing_ it)

Answer (score 0):

The font used in your debugger window and deployed environment do not have accented characters. Change the font settings in Eclipse and your environment (I'm going to assume a console application.)

Comment: At least on the deployed environment (a website) the font has accented characters, because if I type T&iacute;tulo there, it is displayed with the same font as the failed T�tulo. So I guess it is not a fonts issue?